# How can I install new locales for Debian?

Tags: debian, locale, localectl

When I run `localectl show-locales` on Debian, I see

```
$ localectl list-locales
C.UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8
```

Why is this list so abbreviated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Package `locales-all`

To install the locales on Debian you'll want to add,

```
sudo apt install locales-all
```

Then you'll have the bunch,

```
$ localectl list-locales | wc -l
151
```

Including

> C.UTF-8 aa_DJ.UTF-8 af_ZA.UTF-8 an_ES.UTF-8 ar_AE.UTF-8 ar_BH.UTF-8 ar_DZ.UTF-8 ar_EG.UTF-8 ar_IQ.UTF-8 ar_JO.UTF-8 ar_KW.UTF-8 ar_LB.UTF-8 ar_LY.UTF-8 ar_MA.UTF-8 ar_OM.UTF-8 ar_QA.UTF-8 ar_SA.UTF-8 ar_SD.UTF-8 ar_SY.UTF-8 ar_TN.UTF-8 ar_YE.UTF-8 ast_ES.UTF-8 be_BY.UTF-8 bg_BG.UTF-8 bhb_IN.UTF-8 br_FR.UTF-8 bs_BA.UTF-8 ca_AD.UTF-8 ca_ES.UTF-8 ca_FR.UTF-8 ca_IT.UTF-8 cs_CZ.UTF-8 cy_GB.UTF-8 da_DK.UTF-8 de_AT.UTF-8 de_BE.UTF-8 de_CH.UTF-8 de_DE.UTF-8 de_IT.UTF-8 de_LI.UTF-8 de_LU.UTF-8 el_CY.UTF-8 el_GR.UTF-8 en_AU.UTF-8 en_BW.UTF-8 en_CA.UTF-8 en_DK.UTF-8 en_GB.UTF-8 en_HK.UTF-8 en_IE.UTF-8 en_NZ.UTF-8 en_PH.UTF-8 en_SC.UTF-8 en_SG.UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 en_ZA.UTF-8 en_ZW.UTF-8 es_AR.UTF-8 es_BO.UTF-8 es_CL.UTF-8 es_CO.UTF-8 es_CR.UTF-8 es_DO.UTF-8 es_EC.UTF-8 es_ES.UTF-8 es_GT.UTF-8 es_HN.UTF-8 es_MX.UTF-8 es_NI.UTF-8 es_PA.UTF-8 es_PE.UTF-8 es_PR.UTF-8 es_PY.UTF-8 es_SV.UTF-8 es_US.UTF-8 es_UY.UTF-8 es_VE.UTF-8 et_EE.UTF-8 eu_ES.UTF-8 eu_FR.UTF-8 fi_FI.UTF-8 fo_FO.UTF-8 fr_BE.UTF-8 fr_CA.UTF-8 fr_CH.UTF-8 fr_FR.UTF-8 fr_LU.UTF-8 ga_IE.UTF-8 gd_GB.UTF-8 gl_ES.UTF-8 gv_GB.UTF-8 he_IL.UTF-8 hr_HR.UTF-8 hsb_DE.UTF-8 hu_HU.UTF-8 id_ID.UTF-8 is_IS.UTF-8 it_CH.UTF-8 it_IT.UTF-8 ja_JP.UTF-8 ka_GE.UTF-8 kk_KZ.UTF-8 kl_GL.UTF-8 ko_KR.UTF-8 ku_TR.UTF-8 kw_GB.UTF-8 lg_UG.UTF-8 lt_LT.UTF-8 lv_LV.UTF-8 mg_MG.UTF-8 mi_NZ.UTF-8 mk_MK.UTF-8 ms_MY.UTF-8 mt_MT.UTF-8 nb_NO.UTF-8 nl_BE.UTF-8 nl_NL.UTF-8 nn_NO.UTF-8 oc_FR.UTF-8 om_KE.UTF-8 pl_PL.UTF-8 pt_BR.UTF-8 pt_PT.UTF-8 ro_RO.UTF-8 ru_RU.UTF-8 ru_UA.UTF-8 sk_SK.UTF-8 sl_SI.UTF-8 so_DJ.UTF-8 so_KE.UTF-8 so_SO.UTF-8 sq_AL.UTF-8 st_ZA.UTF-8 sv_FI.UTF-8 sv_SE.UTF-8 tcy_IN.UTF-8 tg_TJ.UTF-8 th_TH.UTF-8 tl_PH.UTF-8 tr_CY.UTF-8 tr_TR.UTF-8 uk_UA.UTF-8 uz_UZ.UTF-8 wa_BE.UTF-8 xh_ZA.UTF-8 yi_US.UTF-8 zh_CN.UTF-8 zh_HK.UTF-8 zh_SG.UTF-8 zh_TW.UTF-8 zu_ZA.UTF-8

Answer (score 8):

If you only want some of the locales, run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` as root and select the locales you want.

Or just edit `/etc/locale.gen` which has a long list of commented-out locales by default. Uncomment any locales you wish to enable, and after that, run `locale-gen` as root.

Comment: To edit `/etc/locale.gen` and  run `locale-gen` worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `locale-gen` command to add the desired locale:

You can check the supported locales under  `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`, e,g:

```
sudo locale-gen fr_FR.UTF-8
sudo update-locale
```

The new locale will be added to `localectl` output command:

```
localectl list-locales

C.UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8
fr_FR.UTF-8
```